# Error: selected processor doesn't support (ex.file)

Tags: cmake, arm, rp2040

I tried to write a second bootloader code. I created app file, data file and main file. After that I executed CMake file code. That is completed. But when I try to build cmake file, I get a long error:

```
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s: Assembler messages:
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:1944: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:1945: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:1982: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2135: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2164: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2208: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2209: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2246: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2429: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2458: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2917: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2918: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:2955: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3028: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3057: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3227: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3228: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3265: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3338: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3367: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3472: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3473: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3510: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3631: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:3660: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4141: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4142: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4179: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4228: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4257: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4319: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4320: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4357: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4399: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4428: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4446: Error: selected processor does not support `sev' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4509: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,ipsr'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4601: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,PRIMASK'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4602: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4639: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4681: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4710: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr PRIMASK,r3'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4728: Error: selected processor does not support `wfe' in ARM mode
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4929: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `mrs r3,ipsr'
[build] C:\Users\UMUTKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEVbn3m.s:4987: Error: selected processor does not support `wfe' in ARM mode
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.557
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your toolchain setup or with your CMake code in general. Or you simply write assembler code which is incompatible with the target processor. You need to provide **more details** about your project, in form of [mcve].